# Operand type error while computing returns

Tags: python, pandas, string, typeerror, operands

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

So this code has been written in my Finance class and is basically importing financial stock data given macroeconomic conditions. The problem lies with the variable "macro_etf_df_mom" for some reason the computation of the returns doesnt work. I understood that the problem must lie within this line of code

```
macro_etf_df_mom = macro_etf_df[macro_etf_df.columns[~macro_etf_df.columns.isin(['Date'])]].pct_change()
```

But even if I look around here I am unable to fix it. It would be appreciated if someone would be able to help me!

Thank you!

```
   
#ETF_data = ETF_data.filter(like='Close',axis=1).iloc[:,n:2*n]
ETF_data = ETF_data.dropna()
ETF_data = ETF_data.reset_index() # convert index to column (date)
#ETF_data = ETF_data.rename(columns={'Date':'date'})

# manipulating column names from multiIndex to normal
#ETF_data.columns = ['_'.join(x) for x in ETF_data.columns]
#ETF_data.columns = ETF_data.columns.str.lstrip('Close_')
#ETF_data = ETF_data.rename(columns={'date_':'date'})
#ETF_data['date'] = ETF_data['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

ETF_data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(ETF_data['Date'])

ETF_data['Date'] = ETF_data['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

print('Tickers in us:')
print(tickers)

# load macro factors data
import os
os.chdir('/Users//Downloads/IPM Final Project')
macro_factors = pd.read_csv("macro_ip_int2y.csv")
macro_factors = macro_factors.dropna()

n_macro_factors = len(macro_factors.columns)-1 # because 1st column is date
n_dates = len(macro_factors)
# deleting rows and columns that got unintentionally loaded
#macro_factors = macro_factors.iloc[0:(n_dates+1),0:(n_macro_factors+1)]
print(macro_factors.columns)
macro_factors['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(macro_factors['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
macro_factors['Date'] = macro_factors['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
macro_factors['Date'] = macro_factors['Date'].values.astype('datetime64[M]')  # need to floor the dates on this file in order to marge it with the ETF file
macro_factors['Date'] = macro_factors['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# merging the two data frames
macro_etf_df = pd.merge(ETF_data, macro_factors, on = 'Date') 

macro_etf_df = macro_etf_df.set_index('Date')

# Computing returns!!
macro_etf_df_mom = macro_etf_df[macro_etf_df.columns[~macro_etf_df.columns.isin(['Date'])]].pct_change()

macro_etf_df_mom = macro_etf_df_mom.add_suffix('_mom')
# joining the DF with the MoM rates to the original DF 
macro_etf_df = macro_etf_df.join(macro_etf_df_mom)
#macro_etf_df = macro_etf_df.dropna()







###########################################################################################################

# Macro-Cycle investing or Factor Timing
# The idea is to estimate which factors out(under)perform in which stages of the macro-cycle and position your portfolio accordingly

# lets calculate some stuff up to Dec 2018 and test it in 2019-2021
# 1. we want to know when IP is above (below) average

## example for gdp
# mgdp['current-level-avg'] = mgdp[:(len(mgdp)-24)].mean()


macro_etf_df['m_gdp_av'] = macro_etf_df.m_gdp[:(len(macro_etf_df)-24)].mean()
macro_etf_df['us_2y_av'] = macro_etf_df.us_2y[:(len(macro_etf_df)-24)].mean()

# 2. Create an indicator for the 4 possible states ip > av & us_2y > av, ip < av & us_2y > av, etc...
```

Comment: It looks like you're asking for the pct_change on dates (as strings) hence the error. Assuming that's what you want to do you should convert the dates to a numeric value, such as a time stamp, if you want to perform a numerical operation on them. It's possible that if you left the Date column as a datetime type pandas would be smart enough to do this (I'm not sure) but once you convert them to strings using strftime pandas has no idea anymore that the column represents dates.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
So you suggest I should remove the strftime? I am just a bit confused because the skeleton of this code is from my professor and he managed to run the code like this (there is more to the code than what I copied and he ran it in parts rather than as a whole (not sure if that makes a difference)). 

And the numerical operation should be on the other values rather than the date column (hence my surprise that he was able to run it like this). 

Kind regards,
Vassili

Comment: If this is research code being passed around between you and your prof (and not using version control) chances are you are not running the exact same code :)

Comment: I adapted it - putting in my numbers, changing directories, and adapting variables. The only difference should be the chosen ETFs, and macroeconomic conditions. 

After your comment I just tried and changed the variable "Date" to a numerical one (Closing price of the SP500) and still receive the same error. Im new to coding so any pointer would be appreciated on how to solve this!:)

Comment: Try playing around with a simplified instance of your dataframe (e.g. one containing only the Date column) and see if you can come up with a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you cut out all the unrelated code and just focus on the one problem at hand it might make things clearer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the dataframe data types using

```
print(macro_etf_df.dtypes)
```

and make sure that you are using math on numbers, not strings.  If you see that your dataframe has the type 'objects' then try converting the column to integer.  See the toy code below that starts with all values as strings, so math fails, then converts a column to integer, so math works.

```
row1list = ['100', '2020/03/01']
row2list = ['200', '2020/03/01']
row3list = ['110', '2020/03/02']
df = pd.DataFrame([row1list, row2list, row3list],
                  columns=['number', 'date'])

# fail = df['number'].pct_change()
# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'
print(df.dtypes)
# number    object
# date      object
# dtype: object

df['number'] = df['number'].astype(int)

print(df.dtypes)
# number     int64
# date      object
# dtype: object

works = df['number'].pct_change()
print(works)
# 0     NaN
# 1    1.00
# 2   -0.45
```